# Is there an equivalent of std::set in C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to have a container

```
StdStyleSet<A>
```

of

```
class A : IComparable<A> { ... }
```

which satisfies the properties of std::set. This would especially be:

- The elements themselve are the keys
- Automatically sorted on insertion

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`SortedSet<T>` : see [documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx)  - although technically, it's in the .NET Framework.

For earlier versions, you could use a HashSet and sort using LINQ, not ideal if you're primarily consuming the set in an ordered fashion.  Alternatively you could use a `SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>` with the value as `Object` and store your elements in the keys with nulls for the values.

Comment: That's in .NET 4.. took them long enough.

Comment: Nice! So there is no solution for earlier versions?

Comment: @Danvil - You could use a HashSet and handle any sorting with LINQ, or use a SortedDictionary and store nulls for the values, i.e, use only the keys.

Comment: @DanVil, yes there is, take it from Mono:
http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/System/System.Collections.Generic/SortedSet.cs?revision=155514

Comment: For earlier versions, you *could* use a `Dictionary`/`SortedDictionary` with some dummy value type so you only use the key. But yes, .NET has been ridiculously slow at getting support for even basic data structures.

Comment: Hey guys, these are interesting answers not comments :)

Comment: @Danvil - I've updated my answer with my suggestions for other versions.

Comment: How useful is `SortedSet` compared to `std::set` ?  There's no `[]` indexer , no `upper_bound` or `lower_bound` , etc.  Why is all this left out ?

Comment: std::set also has no [] indexer.